# JasperReports no longer run after move to new server

Tags: jasper-reports

I have been working with JasperReports for about 4 years now. We have moved our application to a new server, and suddenly none of the reports run any more. All they give is the following cryptic error:

```
Error compiling report java source files : /usr/code/myapp/applicationguide_xml_1344313005668_686357.java
```

That's just not enough of an error to do anything about.

All of the JAR files are exactly the same.

I'm using the same version of the Sun JRE.

Google yields nothing helpful.

Has anyone see this before? I see references to the error going all the way back to 2009, but nothing understandable as a solution.

UPDATE:

Here is the code that is failing with the absentee message:

```
JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(reportFile);
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
```

It's the second line.

Comment: different server... so possibly different paths, different permissions/owners/uids? e.g. everything's the same except for the bits that are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JasperCompileManager of course requires access to javac. I did not have jdk-devel installed on my new RedHat machine. After I did:

```
yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel
```

then I no longer received this error.

In order to figure this out, needed a stacktrace since the Jasper error was so cryptic. I installed the Apache Common Lang jar, and printed out my stack trace in a catch block like so:

```
System.out.println(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex));
```

That gave me the underlying error message plain as day.